# ssh to amazon ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

when I create  amazon ubuntu instance from amazon web console and tries to log in to that instance using ssh from any remote computer I am able to log in  but when I create ec2 instance using ansible aws.yml file and tries to do the same, I am unable to connect and got an error `Permission denied (publickey)` from every remote host except from that host in which I ran ansible script. Am I doing something wrong in my ansible file

Here is my ansiblle yml file

```
auth: {
  auth_url: "",
  # This should be your AWS Access Key ID
  username: "AKIAJY32VWHYOFOR4J7Q",
  # This should be your AWS Secret Access Key
  # can be passed as part of cmd line when running the playbook
  password: "{{ password | default(lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY')) }}"
}

# These variable defines AWS cloud provision attributes
cluster: {
  region_name: "us-east-1",     #TODO  Dynamic fetch
  availability_zone: "", #TODO  Dynamic fetch based on region
  security_group: "Fabric",

  target_os: "ubuntu",
  image_name: "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-*",
  image_id: "ami-d15a75c7",
  flavor_name: "t2.medium",  # "m2.medium" is big enough for Fabric
  ssh_user: "ubuntu",
  validate_certs: True,
  private_net_name: "demonet",

  public_key_file: "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd.pub",
  private_key_file: "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd",
  ssh_key_name: "fabric",
  # This variable indicate what IP should be used, only valid values are
  # private_ip or public_ip
  node_ip: "public_ip",

  container_network: {
    Network: "172.16.0.0/16",
    SubnetLen: 24,
    SubnetMin: "172.16.0.0",
    SubnetMax: "172.16.255.0",
    Backend: {
      Type: "udp",
      Port: 8285
    }
  },

  service_ip_range: "172.15.0.0/24",
  dns_service_ip: "172.15.0.4",

  # the section defines preallocated IP addresses for each node, if there is no
  # preallocated IPs, leave it blank
  node_ips: [ ],

  # fabric network node names expect to be using a clear pattern, this defines
  # the prefix for the node names.
  name_prefix: "fabric",
  domain: "fabricnet",

  # stack_size determines how many virtual or physical machines we will have
  # each machine will be named ${name_prefix}001 to ${name_prefix}${stack_size}
  stack_size: 3,

  etcdnodes: ["fabric001", "fabric002", "fabric003"],
  builders: ["fabric001"],

  flannel_repo: "https://github.com/coreos/flannel/releases/download/v0.7.1/flannel-v0.7.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz",
  etcd_repo: "https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/download/v3.2.0/etcd-v3.2.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz",
  k8s_repo: "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.0/bin/linux/amd64/",

  go_ver: "1.8.3",

  # If volume want to be used, specify a size in GB, make volume size 0 if wish
  # not to use volume from your cloud
  volume_size: 8,

  # cloud block device name presented on virtual machines.
  block_device_name: "/dev/vdb"
}
```

**For Login:**

For login using ssh I am doing these steps.

1- Download private key file.

2- chmod 600 private key.

3-ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/sshkeys.pem ubuntu@ec.compute-1.amazonaws.com .

I am getting error `Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: Did you provide the correct instance name for this bit: `ubuntu@ec.compute-1.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the key that you created for connecting to AWS instance.

Got to EC2 dashboard and find instances and click on connect on the running instance that you need to ssh to.

It would be something like 
ssh -i "XXX.pem" ubuntu@ec2-X-XXX-XX-XX.XX-XXX-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Save XXX.pem from security group to your machine.
Not the ssh keygen of your system

Comment: How can I download key-pair after instnace has been in running mode. I downloaded correct key-pair before instance creation but still getting same error

Comment: You should be able to get it from the settings.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/obtaining-aws-key-pair-to-access-amazon-elastic-instances-779166048.html